# How to invite somebody from internet into my newly created chat room?

Tags: discussion, chat, invitation

How to bring discussion from, for example, a Github issue to StackExchange chat room without requiring other peer to register?

**Update:**
The user joing the chat, but reporting that `"You must have 20 reputation on Stack Overflow to talk here."`. What should he do?

Comment: I don't think that's possible. Nor is that kind of use likely to be intended by SE (although I'm sure nobody will mind)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You cannot.  Chat doesn't support anonymous users.  In fact, not only do you need to be a registered user, but you need to have 20 reputation on the chatroom's main site.

Comment: Shall I retool the question into "feature request", at least for the ability to explicitly allow access to freshly registered user to my chat room overriding "min 20 rep"?

Comment: @Vi. That would just make it a duplicate; it's been asked multiple times.

Comment: It is possible for moderators to do this, though it is still a rather convoluted process. Regulars users intentionally don't have access to this specific ability.

Comment: It is appropriate to ask mods just because of you want to "move" some discussion to StackExchange chat?